# state design pattern for sql recordset function

Tags: c++

I have to implement state design pattern in c++ for  sql recordset

I would like to implement movefirst(),moveNext(),movelast(),movePrevious() function in c++

RecExtractionSystem.h:

```
class RecExtractionSystem
{
    States *m_CurrentState;
        public:
            RecExtractionSystem();
             bool ProcessCurrentRec();
             bool ProcessNextRec();
             bool ProcessFirstRec();
             bool ProcessPrevRec();
             bool ProcessLastRec();
             void SetCurrentState(States* currentState);
};
```

States.h:

```
class States
{
public:
      virtual bool ProcessCurrentRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
      virtual bool ProcessNextRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
      virtual bool ProcessFirstRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
      virtual bool ProcessPrevRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);

      virtual bool ProcessLastRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
};

class StopProcessingRec: public States
{
public:
       bool ProcessCurrentRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
};

class ProcessinCurrentRec: public States
{
public:


    bool ProcessFirstRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
    bool ProcessNextRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
    bool ProcessPrevRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);

    bool ProcessLastRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem);
};

Void main()
{
      RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem = new RecExtractionSystem(); 
            pRecExtractionSystem->ProcessNextRec();

}
```

When I call the ProcessNextRec(), it is calling the function of

```
State::ProcessNextRec()
```

But it should call the

```
ProcessinCurrentRec::ProcessNextRec().
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: what is RecExtractionSystem::ProcessNestRec() doing

Comment: The function named ProcessNextRec() will try to fetch the next recordset as the name suggest.

Comment: I am trying to implement state design patter in c++ for SQL recordset, is there anybody c++ expert to help me, because I have never implemented the same in c++

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the override key to each virtual function you reimplement from the base class

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

```
class ProcessinCurrentRec: public States
{
public:

  bool ProcessNextRec(RecExtractionSystem *pRecExtractionSystem) override;

};
```